# Is dcbFreeCallback safe when the registered callback function is running?

Tags: java, memory-management, opencl, lwjgl, dyncall

I am using OpenCL's Java binding provided by lwjgl 3.

When I call the `clSetEventCallback`, I have to pass a callback function to  `clSetEventCallback`. For each `clSetEventCallback` call, I created a new callback function from lwjgl's `CLEventCallback.create`, which eventually calls `dyncall`'s `dcbNewCallback()`.

```
CLEventCallback myCallback = CLEventCallback.create(new CLEventCallbackI {
  ...
});
clSetEventCallback(..., myCallback, ...);
```

Since the callback function I passed to `clSetEventCallback` will be evaluated once and only once, I want to destroy it when it is called by OpenCL.

```
@Override
public void invoke(long event, int status, long user_data) {
  myCallback.close();
}
```

The `myCallback.close()` is provided by lwjgl, and it will eventually calls `dyncall`'s `dcbFreeCallback()`.

The above code runs well for me.

I guess if `dyncall` creates `JMP`-like instructions for all CPUs, then it is safe.

However, I did not find any `dyncall` documentation that allows calling `dcbFreeCallback()` when the registered callback function is running.

So, is it guaranteed safe on all platforms?